# Best practices to handle a Modal data in nextjs 14

Tags: next.js, next.js13

If you have modal that should be shown in an nextjs 14 application, how would you approach that?
We want to fetch as much data on the server as we can, but the content in the modal should only be shown when the user press the modal button. Therefor this data should be fetched on interaction.

We have a couple of options:

- [Intercepting routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes#modals): but this will not work well as just a standalone modal?
- [UrlParamsState](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwq9vePfwkI): Feels a bit hacky imo..
- Fetch data on client using tanstack/serveraction: no fetch on server :(

I would like to understand if there is any best practices around building a modal in nextjs that needs data initially.

Comment: "UrlParamsState: Feels a bit hacky imo..". [In this excellent tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-search-and-pagination#why-use-url-search-params), they recommend `useSearchParams` to manage state for search and pagination.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review the rules and guidelines *before* asking a question.  In particular soliciting opinions about "best practices" or on multiple possible implemention options is considered off topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic